# python "is" returns True but "==" returns False

Tags: python, numpy, comparison

shouldn't "==" return True as long as "is" returns True?

```
In [101]: np.NAN is np.nan is np.NaN
Out[101]: True

In [102]: np.NAN == np.nan 
Out[102]: False

In [103]: np.NaN == np.nan
Out[103]: False

In [104]: np.NaN == np.NAN
Out[104]: False
```

### EDIT:

Are the 3 expressions for float nan *just* legacy of old numpy versions or do they have other usage?

Comment: Welcome to IEEE 754.

Comment: `NaN` cannot be compared to anything, you need to use `np.isnan`.

Comment: +1 for all my friends ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not for [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). You have found one of the exceptions. According to [IEEE 754](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/), NaN is not equal to anything, not even itself:

> A comparison with a NaN always returns an *unordered result* even when comparing with itself.

Not just numpy behaves like this:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan is nan
True
>>> nan == nan
False
```

as will any programming language that implements floating point arithmetic according to the IEEE standard.

The multiple spellings are there to match the common capitalisations for the name. It is an abbreviation for *Not a Number* and different people capitalise the abbreviation differently.

`is` is always going to be `True` for the same object, but `==` is not even guaranteed to return a boolean. From the [`__eq__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__):

> By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an `if` statement), Python will call `bool()` on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

Comment: wish I could +2 for "but == is not even guaranteed to return a boolean"

Comment: question edited a bit, btw, in which case is `__eq__` suggested not to return a boolean?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: SQLAlchemy returns query filter objects, for example. Numpy does similar things, IIRC.

Comment: and 'NaN', 'nan', 'NAN' are just for compatibility, right?

Comment: They are there to match any spelling. Python `float` does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The standard for floating point (IEEE 754) requires that any comparison of NaN values returns not equal. This is common to any programming language that claims to implement IEEE 754, not just Python.

See also Wikipedia's [description of a NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html#ieee-754-floating-point-special-values),

> Special values defined in numpy: nan, inf,
>
> NaNs can be used as a poor-man’s mask (if you don’t care what the
>   original value was)
>
> Note: **cannot use equality to test NaNs.** E.g.:
>
> ...
>
> np.nan == np.nan  # is always False! Use special numpy functions instead. False